# Is "named" an adjective in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure, past-participles

> "Let's pretend that this monkey belongs to a girl ***named*** Bianca"

In this sentence, could anyone help me identify what sentence instruction is given using "named" in this sentence?

Is 'named' here an adjective?

Answer (score 3):

In your example, "named" is a participle.

It isn't quite right to call it an adjective because it can do something that an ordinary adjective can't.   It can take an object.   In this example, the object of "named" is "Bianca".*   This makes sense, since participles are verb forms in the same way that infinitives are verb forms.

However, it does fill the same role in its clause that an adjective would fill.   It (rather, the entire phrase "named Bianca") modifies the noun "girl".

Traditionally, we use the phrasing *parts of speech* to refer to the labels that describe the nature of words (such as *noun* and *adjective*), and we use the phrasing *parts of the sentence* to refer to the labels that describe the use or role of words (such as *subject* or *object*).   I'm not familiar with the phrasing "sentence instruction", but I assume that you're more interested in parts of the sentence than parts of speech.

In your example, "named Bianca" is participial phrase used as a noun's **modifier**.   It does the same job that an adjective phrase or a prepositional phrase might do.

_______________

*  It could be contested that "Bianca" is a complement rather than an object.   The phrase "a girl named Bianca" is related to the clause "someone named a girl Bianca", where "Bianca" is clearly the predicate nominative complement of the direct object "a girl".   Regardless of which side of this contest you favor, the "Bianca" of your example is still an argument of the participle "named".

Comment: I don't think *Bianca* is a Direct Object here. We can't say, for example *Bianca was named her by us*.

Answer (score 1):

This simply means that the girl's name is Bianca. It is a way of telling names. A girl **named** Lyka; a boy **named** Jack and so on.

No, it serves as a ['verb'.](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/name_2)

The word 'named' cannot be an adjective in any sense.