# How to know which one is right between past and present passive?

Tags: sentence-choice

How to know which one is correct?

1. Friendship that is built on trust has bright future.(passive)
2. Friendship built on trust has bright future.(past)

Why we can't use build? I asked this question but still have doubts. I mean why passive and past tense make sense when we use build it didn't make sense according to the answers that I got.

Comment: The words ***that is*** (or ***which is***) are completely optional in such contexts (we could say *A problem **that is** shared is a problem halved*, but we don't normally bother with that highlighted part). It's not really relevant to talk about "passive" or "past" here - it's just an example of a (past) participle used adjectivally. But note that regardless of whether you include ***which / that is*** or not, you still need an indefinite article with ***a** bright future*.

Comment: Participle used  as an adjective. Could you please tell me more on that.

Comment: See [Be + past participle](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106778/be-past-participle) and [Is “named” an adjective in this sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73524/is-named-an-adjective-in-this-sentence) (and probably others).

Comment: If I use 'build' would it be a wrong one?

Comment: That would be completely wrong, yes. Consider *Friendship **built on trust** is important*, where it should be easy to see that we'd still have a syntactically valid sentence if we removed the highlighted "adjectival" part *(Friendship is important)*. Or we could add a simple one-word adjective: ***Close** friendship is important* (single-word adjectives usually go *before* the noun). But it wouldn't make any sense at all to say *Friendship **build** on trust is important*.

Comment: The final part of your question seems to be asking something quite different than what went before. What does the comparison between the two sentences you provide have to do with *build*? What is your actual question? (What are "the answers" that you got?)